# c++: Is this a clang's bug of namespace leak?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

I've got a very simple program like below:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int count=10;
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it using clang on mac, I got error:

```
test.cpp:5:19: error: reference to 'count' is ambiguous
    for(int i=0;i<count;++i)
                  ^
test.cpp:3:5: note: candidate found by name lookup is 'count'
int count=10;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:1112:1: note:
      candidate found by name lookup is 'std::__1::count'
count(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, const _Tp& __value_)
^
1 error generated.
```

How strange it is, the count is inside scope "std::__1", but seem to confuse "std". Is this a namespace leak bug of clang compiler? I tried the same with gcc on linux, no such problem.

Any explanations?

Comment: `__1` is an inline namespace.

Comment: Welcome to inline namespaces.